# Will this adapter work with wireshark?

Tags: kali-linux, wireshark, sniffing

Will the Alfa awus036acm with mt7612u chipset work with wireshark 6.0.2 on Kali 6.0.0 for packet sniffing tcp,udp,dns,http,etc? I have seen both negative and positive reviews on it so I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it will work on Kali 6.0.0

It is recommened by [AirCrack](https://www.aircrack-ng.org/%7E%7EV:/doku.php?id=faq#what_is_the_best_wireless_card_to_buy)  as one of the best cards for packet sniffing & other.

as you have seen positive and negative reviews, its upto you to select it if it suits your need.